# How to use tweepy to get tweets with a particular hashtag and all the previous tweets of that user?

Tags: tweepy

```
from Twython import Twython

TWITTER_APP_KEY = 'xxxxx' 
TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxxx' 
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxx'

t = Twython(app_key=TWITTER_APP_KEY, 
            app_secret=TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, 
            oauth_token=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
            oauth_token_secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

search = t.search(q='#throwback', count=100)

tweets = search['statuses']

for tweet in tweets:
  print tweet['id_str'], '\n', tweet['text'], '\n\n\n'
```

From this code i can get the tweets with #throwback. But now if I want to get all the previous tweets of that user then how should i do it.

eg. from this let's assume that i got 2 tweets from 3 different user as:
tweet 1: what a day it was #throwback (from user 1) .
tweet 2: I love this #throwback (from user 2)

then how will i get the last n tweets of user 1 and user 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the usernames of the users in some list and then use my crawler to get tweets of those users by small editing:
[TweetCrawler](https://github.com/Sy-Muzammil/Tweet-Crawlers/blob/master/tweetsMedia.py).In this crawler you need not to use filter on tweets containing media urls in code you can remove that, and you need not to store new users mentioned in downloaded tweets, you can also remove that as well.You have to download tweets by users only , and you need only that part of code. If any query feel free to ask.